# Magento 2: XML before="-" and before="_"

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I'm sure this is a very basic question but as the description is so generic, I'm having trouble researching it.

I've noticed in the layout **XML** files.

- before="_" (before with underscore)
- before="-" (before with dash)

Could someone explain what **before** does and what the result is with the dash or underscore?

Thank you

Comment: check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after

Comment: where did you find `before="_"` ?

Comment: @Marius there's no reference to `before="_"` in Magento 2.0.4 at least

Comment: Uh oh... I'm sure I saw before="_" somewhere! Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

`before="-"`  mean's place this block before all other elements
their is not anything like `before="_"`